# Laravel rest api security

Tags: android, rest, api, laravel-5

I have a laravel backend which has rest api. But I want my rest api to be used only by my android app. So how do my backend know that the request is coming from my android app only and not from web or another app? 
NB: I don't want the users to accept some login challenges.

Comment: It is impossible to completely block it from the public, but there are some ways to make that a bit harder.

Comment: Always send a value with any query to the server just to specify its from your app. or you can create a separate route for your application

Comment: In that case anybody can decompile my app to see the query string and build their own app.

Comment: Have a separate url endpoint for android devices

Comment: you need Auth Token, Custom headers, Secret Key, Middleware for your api..then its safe

Answer (score 0):

you can use jwt. Each time you execute a request you must obtain the token. The token ensures that the user belongs to their service. The token must be saved in some way in your android app to return that response to the api rest.

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Also keep in mind protect your endpoints in the api rest:

```
Route::middleware(['jwt_auth'])->group(function(){

    Route::group(['prefix'=> 'V1'],function(){
            Route::post('/endpoint', 'V1\EndointController@store');
    });

});
```

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.